# Can Sith crystals be "bled" by Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, kyber-crystal

Since I know Jedi crystals or normal crystals in general can be "bled" by Sith to turn red from the anger and hatred infused from a Sith's soul, I started wondering it it can work in reverse, so a Sith crystal is "healed" to turn yellow, green, blue, purple, or the many other colors that Kyber crystals attune to?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### They can be unbled, as done by Ahsoka Tano

> The crystals that had powered his lightsaber were no longer contained by metal, but their song had not dimmed. She held them in one hand, almost shaking as the familiarity of them coursed through her...her mind's eye sorted the preassembled components and those she had just retrieved into order, locking each into place with the others....when she turned them on, **they shone the brightest white**.

*Chapter 28*

> "I've never seen white ones before", Bail mused.
>
> "They used to be red", Ahsoka said. "When the creature had them, they were red. But I heard them before I ever saw him on Raada, and knew they were meant for me."
>
> "You changed their nature?", he asked.
>
> "I restored them", Ahsoka replied. "I freed them. The red crystals were corrupted by the dark side when those who wielded them bent them to their will. They call it making the crystal bleed. That's why the blade is red."

*Chapter 30*

Source: Ahsoka (novel)